# Making bubble sort pure and efficient

Tags: javascript, algorithm, bubble-sort

### Background

I am re-writing a series of algorithms together with a colleague that we are going to later on publish in a packet for the community.

To start, I picked the typical buble sort algorithm.

### Objectives

1. the function must be pure
2. it must be efficient
3. it must obey the complexities listed in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort

Please note that by "being pure" it doesn't mean that it's inside code cannot have impurity. It merely means that the PUBLIC API of the function must be pure and it must not affect anything outside of its scope.

### Code

```
const isFunction = require("lodash.isfunction");
const cloneDeep = require("lodash.clonedeep");

const defaultCompare = require("./defaultCompare");

const bubble = ( array, fnCompare = defaultCompare ) => {

    if( !isFunction(fnCompare) )
        throw new Error("fnCompare must be a function");

    if(!Array.isArray(array))
        throw new Error("array must be an Array");

    if (array.length === 0)
        return [];

    const clonedArray = cloneDeep(array);

    return recursiveSort( clonedArray, clonedArray.length, fnCompare );
};

const recursiveSort = ( array, unsortedLength, fnCompare ) => {
    if( unsortedLength === 1 )
        return array;

    let swapped = false;
    for( let i = 0; i < unsortedLength - 1; i++ ){

        if( fnCompare( array[i], array[i + 1] ) > 0 ){
            const temp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[i + 1];
            array[i + 1] = temp;
            swapped = true;
        }
    }

    //Ensure O(n) if array is already ordered
    if(!swapped)
        return array;

    return recursiveSort( array, unsortedLength - 1, fnCompare );
};

module.exports = bubble;
```

### What do I want?

I am looking for any flaws in the code that could compromise objectives 1 and 3.

I am also looking to ways of improving its efficiency, since I am sure if the garbage collector likes recursivity that much (tail call optimisation is not implemented in most browers yet ...).

Comment: Why recursive? Won't that put a limit on number of items that can be sorted? Also, why are you creating a dependency on third party libraries like *lodash*?

Comment: Recursivity is something I am actually worried about, that is true. I may have to end up removing it. As for lodash, I am not using the entire thing, just two functions that have been tested by millions of people. I don't see it as a problem. Specially because since this is to be pure **I need to deepClone the array**.

Comment: But why create a dependency on it at first place and that too for something as simple as `isFunction` and `cloneDeep` for which there are simpler plain JS solutions available?

Comment: If you can do it with no dependencies then it will be preferred by most developers.  I definitely wouldn't want to include a 3rd party library in a 3rd party library.  Honestly, I'd see the dependency and immediately judge your skills as a developer, and therefore my faith in your solution.  It would be little to none.

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix You don't need to *deep* clone an array for sorting. You just need to create a new array containing the *same* objects (in a different order)

Comment: Well, I understand where you are comming from. But I personally don't agree with your opinion. If I was requiring the entire download of the library I could give you some points, but I am not. Life is made of choices and if you feel that someone who uses well tested sofwtare to develop faster is not worth your time then I am sorry to hear that. I am not trying to please both Greeks and Trojans anyway :P

Comment: I would never call Bubble sort "efficient"…

Comment: @Bergi and since the function is to be pure, I need to deepClone the objects. Might as well just clone the entire array at first and then play with it. And no, I am very well aware of bubble sort's issues. This is just the starting point :P

Comment: You shouldn't be cloning the array anyways, mutation of original array is okay and expected as well (it happens with JS Array.sort also). Leave it to the developer to make that decision.

Comment: Not sure why you're asking this question if you're going to take constructive responses and say *"I'm not trying to please everyone"*.  Seems like a waste of your time.  Each to their own I guess.  Good luck with your project.

Comment: @gurvinder372 Writing a pure function is totally fine, especially as part of a functional-minded package. You might want to call it `sorted` instead of `sort`

Comment: @Archer I am asking you gentlemen to help me with this exercise. The rules of engagement are very clear (see objectives). If you do not agree with them, then please feel free to leave. No one is forcing you to give your opinion, instead I kindly ask you leave space for those who actually wish to help :D

Comment: @Bergi as in bubbleSorted ? Could you elaborate on your idea please?

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix I was helping - you just don't agree with me.  I will always respond to you as I consider it rude not to, so if you wish me to stop expressing my opinions then just leave me gone, as I was.  As I said, good luck with your project :)

Comment: Your second objective says, "It must be efficient." The bubble sort algorithm itself is not particularly efficient to start with, and your implementation involves additional complexity. If your goal is to publish your package for others to use, I would suggest selecting a more efficient sorting algorithm than bubble sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding objective 1, your code does fine at being pure - it just clones everything.

This does not go well with objective 3 though. While the complexity of `recursiveSort` is the expected `O(n²)`, cloning the entire contents of the array puts an additional burden on the complexity, which now depends not only on the length of the input array but also on the size and depth of the elements. Since a sort does not mutate the elements anyway, this is pointless - you can and should just return a new array with the original objects. A major goal of purity is to allow for sharing!

So use

```
function bubbleSorted(array, fnCompare = defaultCompare) {
    if (typeof fnCompare != "function")
        throw new Error("fnCompare must be a function");
    if (!Array.isArray(array))
        throw new Error("array must be an Array");

    return recursiveSort(array.slice(), array.length, fnCompare);
}
```

Notice also that you have unnecessary many base cases. Your algorithm should only need to stop when `swapped` is false. You do not need to do extra tests on the array length being `0` or `1`.

Comment: I am most definitely **not** doing a selection sort good Sir. I don't check for mins and maxes. I check elements 2 by 2 and if element 2 > element 1, I swap them. I encourage you to follow code execution with a debugger. You did pose an interesting question about purity however. I will research into it.

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix Oops, brain fart. That `swapped` variable looked like you were checking in the loop whether/where to do a swap, and then do one swap after the loop.